# Enlarge font size of function names in source code like Source Insight

Tags: fonts, c++

Source Insight can show function names in a larger font. Can Emacs display function names with a larger font and different color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily.

press `M-x` RET `customize-face` RET `font-lock-function-name-face` RET and you'll get the customization menu for function name face. You can change any attribute you want(font weight, height, color, etc.) and **don't** forget to click on `Apply and Save` and save for future sessions.