# enlarge font of functions only in C code

Tags: faces, cc-mode

I am trying to do exactly [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28064/enlarge-font-size-of-function-names-in-source-code-like-source-insight) for my C code, but once I edit latex, the setting is still active in uncomfortable places. I need to preserve the setting once I exit emacs and in all the buffers with C code.

How can I restrict the behavior to only buffers with C code?

**This is what I have in .emacs**

```
(defun my-c-mode-faces ()
  '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "dark gray"))))
  '(font-lock-function-name-face ((t (:foreground "#fce94f" :weight bold :height 1.5))))
  '(font-lock-keyword-face ((t (:foreground "#b4fa70" :weight bold)))))
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-faces)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify-face for a specific buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7281/how-to-modify-face-for-a-specific-buffer)  See also how to use this concept (`face-remap-add-relative)` with a major-mode-hook:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008006/2112489 .  The O.P. would probably want to use the `c-mode-hook`, but C-mode uses a few additional hooks that could also potentially be used.

Comment: thanks for your comment, I want the setting to be available in all buffers, not only in one. but only buffers with c code. I'm just coming from gedit to emacs, I still need to learn what are the minor, major modes, faces and what you mention: hooks

Comment: If you look at both examples that I linked above, and use the `c-mode-hook` as it relates to the second example (with the desired face), then you will be all set.  Every time you open a buffer in c-mode or switch to c-mode, the `face-remapping-alist` variable will be set accordingly and the face will be buffer-local.  As in the famous old commercial with Life cereal -- "try it, you'll like it".  If you actually try the second linked example with the `c-mode-hook` as it relates to the desired face, and if you really have problems, then edit your question to show what you have tried ...

Comment: I still have the setting everywhere, I edit to include what I have in .emacs. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun my-c-mode-faces ()
  (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-comment-face
                              '(:foreground "dark gray"))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-function-name-face
                              '(:foreground "#fce94f" :weight bold :height 1.5))
  (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-keyword-face
                              '(:foreground "#b4fa70" :weight bold)))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-faces)
```